# Change Table names in derby database using entitymanager

Tags: java, rename, derby, entitymanager

I am using an APACHE DERBY database, and basing my database interactions on EntityManager, and I don't want to use JDBC class to build a query to change my tables' names (i just need to put a prefix to each new user to the application, but have the same structure of tables), such as:

```
//em stands for EntityManager object
Query tableNamesQuery= em.createNamedQuery("RENAME TABLE SCHEMA.EMP_ACT TO EMPLOYEE_ACT");
em.executeUpdate();
// ... rest of the function's work
// The command works from the database command prompt but i don't know how to use it in a program
//Or as i know you can't change system tables data, but here's the code
Query tableNamesQuery= em.createNamedQuery("UPDATE SYS.SYSTABLES SET TABLENAME='NEW_TABLE_NAME' WHERE TABLETYPE='T'");
em.executeUpdate();
// ... rest of the function's work
```

My questions are :

- This syntax is correct?
- Will it work?
- Is there any other alternative?
- Should I just use the SYS.SYSTABLES and find all the tables that has 'T' as tabletype and alter their name their, will it change the access name ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the RENAME TABLE statement: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqljrenametablestatement.html

**Don't** just issue update statements against the system catalogs, you will corrupt your database.